# How does lightning affect electricity?

Tags: electricity

We often face lightning during bad weather.

I often observe that before a horrible sound of lightning, the power of electricity seems almost gone for a while.

Lights seem almost off. But the duration of this is very short. May be less than half of a second.

And sometimes, electricity goes by bursting transformer.

Why does this happen?

How does lightning affect on electricity actually?

Comment: The problem is not the thunderclap, it's the lightning.

Comment: @manetsus: Did you do any research before asking the question? Lightning _is_ electrical.

Comment: @transistor sure, lightning is electrical, so? I am not an expert in this field, so I have to learn through asking skilled people like you. Thanks.

Comment: No, you research by reading the thousands of articles on the web and then ask for clarification on points you don't understand.

Comment: @ThePhoton Having some more research, I found that I actually talked about thunderclap, not only lightning. Thanks.

Comment: @transistor okay, but I have less capability to catch the right thing easily from the web. A little bit effort of you may eradicate lots of confusion in our mind. Thanks.

Comment: @manetsus From the way you phrased your last comments, it seems possible that you don't realise that thunder is not different from lighting, it's the sound that lightning makes.

Comment: You need to take Mark Twain to heart: "Thunder is good. Thunder is impressive. But it is lightning that does the work."

Comment: @RogerRowland Okay. Somebody told me that thunderclap is that which falls and lightning just flashes, but does not fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightning means a very big amount of electric charges which are trying to reach the ground through the easiest available path . They try to find it normally at heights , the peak of towers , tall buildings , trees or electricity cables .

So if they find the electrical network cables at which the height is fairly enough for them to get access , they start flowing toward ground or any lower degree of electrical potential . That s the time when you see a long shiny line inside the clouds in the sky . 
These charges will conclude in thousand volts of voltage . Hence it will easily damage the electrical facilities and transmission tools . 
For avoiding these damages , there are some ways to convey the lightning energy in a safe manner and secondly some protective equipment like fuses which are used in electrical industry .

Answer (score 2):

One scenario of such effect is when lightning strikes part of the power distribution system (such as overhead lines). The strike induces high voltage pulses which propagate through the system conductor. This voltage can cause damage if special hardware to diminish its effects are not included in the power distribution system.

This special hardware may force the distribution system to close parts of the distribution network. Since the load remains the same on the consumer side and the network is reduced  due the fault, the power may momentarily fall until distribution network settles. This causes the dim you explain.